# Silverlight Project - Setting Reference to Copy Local false not working

Tags: silverlight

Why is it that when my Silverlight project is built, the output directory contains a bunch of culture specific directories:

- ar\System.Windows.Controls.resources.dll
- bg\System.Windows.Controls.resources.dll
- ca\System.Windows.Controls.resources.dll
- etc etc etc

Also the root of the build output contains:

- System.Xml.Linq.dll
- System.windows.Controls.dll

I have gone through the projects in my solution and made sure that "Copy Local" is set to false for all the referances of the mentioned dll files. 
Those 2 files were set to true, but I did switch them to false. Despite my effort to google an answer, I remain stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check that ALL REFERENCED ASSEMBLIES are set to copy local false.

Comment: I have set copy local to False, and i get runtime error that namespace is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

You have dependent libraries or DLLs or references that expect these SDK assemblies.

Those directories contain the language-specific resource files and will be there if the System.Windows.Controls assembly is included in any way in any part of your project or its dependencies.

Comment: I have a custom message window control that is sub classed from System.Windows.Controls.ChildWindow. I really do not need all those language specific resources.

Comment: Apparently I missed some of the referenced assemblies that were set to copy local true. It is building correctly now, with only dll's and debug info being generated.